# How to find the APDU command from a magnetic strip card

Tags: smartcard, apdu

I want to find the APDU command from my magnetic strip

I want to find the APDU command and rewrite it on a blank card.

I want to learn how to read apdu……………….I will pay anyone who can help me please ..I don't know anything to reading the card number and what is APDU?Can anybody help me to solve out? Thank you…………………

Answer (score 0):

Magnetic Strip cards do not communicate with APDU commands, only an ISO-7816 smart card uses APDU commands. A magnetic stripe card is like a cassette tape, there is only data recorded or written to that media and follows the ISO-7810 specification on how that is done.

Answer (score -1):

Magnetic cards are are ancient ancestors of smart cards. Since they have no intelligence whatsoever - imagine them as a plastic card with a glued-on magnetic stripe - the magnetic card reader/writer is the instance understanding commands.
Note that there are readers without possibility to write at all. (Swipe-through readers don't have the precision needed for reliable writing, you need a motor for that).

Look at the manual of the magnetic reader/writer, there was little standarization and most likely, the reader is attached to a computer using a serial RS-232 interface. While there are reserved data object IDs on smart cards inventend to store track1..track3 for an migration period, even those are now outdated since ages.